# Problems for installing fiware-cygnus

Tags: maven, fiware-cygnus

I have problems for installing cygnus for testing purposes
I already installed it weeks ago, and it worked until I reset the OS installation of my pc

Right now I have this error during installation
apache-maven-3.2.5/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /opt/fiware-cygnus/cygnus-common: No such file or directory

I wonder if anything changed from the Cygnus git repo.

Could you please help to overcome this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Which version are you trying to install? Which was the version that worked for you in the past? How are you trying to install it? Which is the output of the installation process?